# Kotlin: How do you execute something as soon as a suspend function returns?

Tags: kotlin, suspend

Is there the possibility to execute a code block directly after a suspend function returns?

Let's say we have a suspend function that sets some variable x that i want to use afterwards:

```
suspend fun loadSomething() {..}
```

Is there any way to do something like

```
loadSomething().whenDone {<use x somehow>}
```

?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#sequential-by-default

Comment: If you have a shared variable what are you doing to manage [synchronizated access](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html) to it? I suggest making the shared state completely private, and add a lambda parameter `fun loadSomething(whenDone: (Any) -> Unit)` which will be invoked internally when `x` is ready.

Comment: @aSemy I don't agree. One of the main goals of coroutines and suspend functions is to get rid of asynchronous callback hell. And now you suggest replacing suspend function with a callback. I would call it a step back. It makes sense to encapsulate loading and synchronization inside `loadSomething()` as you suggest, but then it should just return the result, not provide it through callback.

Comment: @broot I don't appreciate your tone. There are some situations where lambdas as parameters are more suitable than a return value, and others which are not. If you want to make a suggestion go ahead, but as the question is lacking context it's rude and dismissive to flatly dismiss one approach as 'hell'.

Comment: "Callback hell" is a very common phrase used to describe what Kotlin coroutines solve. I don't think use of that phrase implies a negative tone toward the reader. The OP is asking how to do something with coroutines, so your comment could be interpreted as saying they should use a callback *combined* with coroutines, which would be messy and unnecessary. That seems to be the way broot read it (and how I did,too), but maybe you were suggesting it as an alternative to coroutines.

Comment: @aSemy I apologize, I didn't mean to offend you. "hell" wasn't at all directed specifically at you. "[callback hell](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/callback_hell)" is a common term describing one of main problems with APIs based on callbacks. And suspend functions were invented to fight this problem, so it is hard to not mention it in this context. But I agree, we know almost nothing about OP's design, so we don't know which solution could work the best here.

Answer (score 1):

Suspend functions are synchronous, so there is no need for such operators. You do this as normal:

```kotlin
loadSomething()
// use x
```

Full example:

```kotlin
var x: String? = null

suspend fun main() {
    loadSomething()
    println(x) // prints "loaded"
}

suspend fun loadSomething() {
    delay(500)
    x = "loaded"
}
```